# Heroku HttpServlet: doGet() is being called instead of doPost()

Tags: java, http, servlets, heroku

(Servelt is hosted on Heroku)

In my Servlet, i implemented creating a user a POST method. Even though I've implemented it as a POST method, whenever I make a request to the server with a /createAccount URI using POST, my doGet() method is being called instead. Why is it that my doGet() method is being called instead of my doPost() method?

Github for code: https://github.com/jchio001/AravindsBackend/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java

Raw code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.*;

public class Main extends HttpServlet{

    private static String TABLE_CREATION = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (user_id SERIAL, name varchar(32), " +
            "about_me varchar(1024), village varchar(32), zip_code int, phone_number varchar(16), email varchar(32));";
    private static String TABLE_CREATION_2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Connections (requester_id int, target_id int, status varchar(32));";

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE_CREATION);
            stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE_CREATION_2);
            resp.getWriter().print("I did get X.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setStatus(500);
            resp.getWriter().print("Table creation error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                resp.getWriter().print("Failed to close connection: " + getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE_CREATION);
            stmt.executeUpdate(TABLE_CREATION_2);
            resp.getWriter().print("I did post.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setStatus(500);
            resp.getWriter().print("Table creation error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                jb.append(line);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            resp.setStatus(400);
            resp.getWriter().print("Couldn't read in request body: " + getStackTrace(e));
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jb.toString());
            if (req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/createAccount")) {
                resp.setStatus(200);
                resp.getWriter().print("Creating!");
                String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String about_me = jsonObject.getString("about_me");
                String village = jsonObject.getString("village");
                String zip_code = jsonObject.getString("zip_code");
                String phone_number = jsonObject.getString("phone_number");
                String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                String update_sql = "INSERT INTO profile (name, about_me, village, zip_code, phone_number, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                try {
                    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(update_sql);
                    stmt.setString(1, name);
                    stmt.setString(2, about_me);
                    stmt.setString(3, village);
                    stmt.setString(4, zip_code);
                    stmt.setString(5, phone_number);
                    stmt.setString(6, email);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                    stmt.close();
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    resp.getWriter().print("SQL ERROR @POST: " + getStackTrace(e));
                }
            }
            else {
                resp.setStatus(404);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e1) {
            resp.setStatus(400);
            resp.getWriter().print("Error parsing request JSON: " + getStackTrace(e1));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            resp.setStatus(500);
            resp.getWriter().print("Error creating SQL statement: " + getStackTrace(e));
        }

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                resp.getWriter().print("Failed to close connection: " + getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    }

    private static Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
      URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

      String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
      String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
      String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + dbUri.getPath();

      return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(System.getenv("PORT")));
      ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
      context.setContextPath("/");
      server.setHandler(context);
      context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new Main()), "/*");
      server.start();
      server.join();
    }

    public static String getStackTrace(Throwable aThrowable) {
      final Writer result = new StringWriter();
      final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
      aThrowable.printStackTrace(printWriter);
      return result.toString();
    }

}
```

EDIT: Screenshot of what POSTMAN looks like when I make the HTTP request (including all info needed to make the same request):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8h0m.png
As one can see, my output is "I did get X", which means that doGet() is being executed.

Comment: Show us the client code where you make the request.

Comment: I used postman to make the request.

Comment: Set to POST, typed in URL, put in a body, and then sent it. I'll edit with a picture of how my postman looks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Resolved it by nuking the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Send POST request**

To send a POST request with data associated with it, follow these steps:

- Be sure the Normal tab is selected, which is the default.
- Supply the request URL. Be sure to place the actual values in the URL as the environment variables used in the curl statements will not be defined here.
- Choose POST to be the selected HTTP method.
- Click the Headers button, and supply the Header - Value pair Content-Type - application/json.
- Click the URL params button. For parameter configuration first select raw, then from the dropdown select JSON.
- Paste the configuration JSON into the area provided.
- Click Send.
  (If you have recently submitted a request you may not be asked to authenticate again.) You will be presented with a pop-up window to enter your credentials. Do so and click OK.

Further information here:
[Use Postman for HTTP Requests](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/perform/player-management/guides/postman.html)

Comment: My post has been updated with a SS of the response after sending the POST request.

Comment: @JonathanChiou, What are you sending in the request?  Values,JSON string ?

Comment: I'm sending in a JSON.

Comment: {
    name : "Dood",
    about_me : "I am cool.",
    village : "Bettany",
    zip_code : 94538,
    phone_number: "5555555555",
    email: "derp@durdle.com"
}

Comment: The issue is not the string; the issue is that doPost() won't execute even though it's a POST request. The string itself will not change this.

Comment: @JonathanChiou, try this string:
{
 "name": "Dood",
 "about_me": "I am cool.",
 "village": "Bettany",
 "zip_code": 94538,
 "phone_number": "5555555555",
 "email": "derp@durdle.com"
}

Comment: doPost() never executes, so it doesn't matter what string is being put in.

Comment: Yes, It's still running doGet(). It doesn't matter what string is being fed in because doGet() is the function being called, not doPost().

Comment: @JonathanChiou  What are you setting the content type header to?

Comment: My screenshot has a picture of the header that's being sent.